# A black metal song in episode 41 of My Hero Academia

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

There's a song that plays in *My Hero Academia* season 2, episode 41 around 20:45-20:58ish when the villains showed up during the poison gas/tree burning scene. It was growling black metal type vocals and drums.

What is that song?

Answer (score 1):

It’s Yuki Hayashi's July 10th or 開闢行動隊-総攻撃 by 林 ゆうき

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, the only artist mentioned in the end credits is Miwa. After hours of searching all I could come up with was this video of her doing a metal cover. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eVHPqmgvrE It sounds close, but Im not 100% sold on it. But it does prove she can sing that style so perhaps its a new song by her. If that is the case we will have to wait for the OST.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7dYMxIpJis

It's call All out Attack on the MHA soundtrack.